# maximum number of perfect matchings of $K_{2n}$ such that no edge appears in two different matchings

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given a complete graph $G=K_{2n}$, construct a set $P$, such that each element $p$ of $P$ is a perfect matching of $G$ and every two elements $p_i,p_j$ don't share a common edge of $G$.What's the maximum cardinality of $P$?

I'd like to calculate the maximum number of perfect matchings of a complete graph of order $2n$, such that no edge appears in two different matchings and find an algorithm to construct one enumeration of such perfect matchings if possible.

I believe each such set could contain up to ${{2n}\choose{2} }/n = 2n-1$ perfect matchings, but I was unable to construct one or prove such enumeration must exist.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_factorization#Complete_graphs

Comment: Thanks! I get it now.